# SQL Conditional column data return in a select statement

Tags: sql

Here is a simplication of the problem: I have a select that looks like this:

```
Select ID, Assignee, WorkStream from assignees;
```

And a snap shot of the data returned looked like this

```
1|Joe Soap|Internal

2|Mrs Balls|External
```

What I would like to do is have the select not display the Assignee name if the worksteam is internal. Instead to display the Workstream.

So for example the outcome I want to achieve would be this:

```
1|Internal|Internal

2|Mrs Balls|External
```

I hope this makes sense? Basically a conditional select that can detect if a certain column contains a certain value, then replace another columns value with [whatever].

EDIT I want to achieve something like this:

```
Select ID, if (workstream='internal' select Workstream as Assignee - else - select Assignee as Assigneee), WorkStream from assignees;
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You didn't mention your DBMS but a searched `CASE` statement works in all major DBMS's I know off.

```
SELECT  ID
        , CASE WHEN WorkStream = 'Internal'
               THEN WorkStream
               ELSE Assignee
          END AS Assignee
        , Workstream
FROM    assignees
```

---

Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

> **CASE**
>
> Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible
>   result expressions.

Comment: Is there a way to select multiple columns conditionally? I need to select columns depending on the joined table, otherwise I end up with columns from all tables.

Comment: @akinuri - not sure if I understand your requirement correctly. I'd say, yes offcourse but perhaps better to post an example and expected result.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers My question was about an [attempted solution](https://github.com/akinuri/dump/blob/master/sql/notes/select-columns-conditionally.sql) to a previous [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951653/how-to-handle-different-types-of-users-when-loggin-in).

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT ID, 
       CASE WorkStream  WHEN 'Internal' THEN 'INTERNAL' ELSE Assignee as Assignee,    WorkStream  from assignees
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Why is there Workstream between CASE and WHEN?