# compare two columns and select only one with sql query

Tags: sql, linq, case

I have two columns, let's say `col1` and `col2`. both of them is `float`

It's always `if col1 = 0 then col2 > 0`  or  `col1 > 0 then col2 = 0`

I want to select only one column which is greater than zero.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare two columns for equality in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632792/how-do-i-compare-two-columns-for-equality-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Conditional column data return in a select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290994/sql-conditional-column-data-return-in-a-select-statement)

Comment: Sounds like your statement is:
If `col1` equals zero, then `col2` is always greater than 0, so I would want to select `col2`. If `col2` equals zero, then `col1` is always greater than 0, so I would want to select `col1`. If this is true, then @DineshDB has the correct Answer. @Mischa Answer will provide the exact same result however since one or the other is always zero. N+0=N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the two is always zero?

`SELECT col1+col2`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Col1=0 THEN COL2 ELSE Col1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Col1 > 0 THEN COL1 ELSE Col2 END from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for linq

```
from t in Table
select new { Col = ( t.col1  > 0 )?t.col1 : t.col2  }
```