# How to handle different types of users when loggin in?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

In an application I've been building, I have a `users` table. The users represent a firm's staff. I also implemented a role/permission system. Permissions are assigned to roles (staff, manager, director, etc.), and roles are assigned to users. Permissions prohibit the use of certain actions in the app.

Now, I'm introducing another user type: customer (will also be able to log into the app). The customer fields are different from the user fields, so I can't store the customer information in `users` table (and create a role for customers).

<sub>(Normally, just creating a customer role for the customers and store the custumers in the `users` table would be fine, but since the fields are different, I don't think that's an option.)</sub>

First, I thought about creating a seperate table for the customers, but I'm not sure if that's okay, because when someone tries to log into the app, I have to check two tables (`users` and `customers`) for the log-in credentials. What if I introduce a third user type? Check three tables? That doesn't seem practical/efficient.

So I thought about seperating the log-in credentials from users, and ended up with three tables:

- `users` will hold log-in credentials
- `staff` will hold staff meta/profile information
- `customers` will hold customer information (same as `staff`)

This way, I can introduce many different types of users. And if I know what I'm looking for, I can get the record. For example, say I want to get/query a staff, I can just do:

```
SELECT * FROM staff
JOIN users USING (user_id);
```

The problem is how do I query `users` when I don't know what I'm looking for? I mean, the logged user can be a staff, customer, etc. I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
JOIN [specific_table_name] USING (user_id);
```

How do I know which type of user just logged in? I could store the user type (the target table name?) in `users`, but will it help in a (single) query? I mean, find the user in `users` (using credentials), and then join the user information from another table (`staff`, `customers`, etc.)?

Currently, I'm thinking about doing two queries. First is to get the user (credential) record, and the second is to get user (say, profile) information (using a field `type` from user record).

Of course I'll be doing this in PHP. For example (not real code):

```
$email = "someone@example.com";
$user  = get_user($email); // SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "someone@example.com"

switch ($user["type"]) {
    case "staff":
        $user = get_staff($email); // SELECT * FROM staff JOIN users USING (user_id) WHERE email = "someone@example.com"
        break;
    case "customer":
        $user = get_customer($email);
        break;
    // ...
}

// how it's done doesn't really matter. the thing is "type" needs to be checked to get the corresponding user info
```

Is this best way to handle this? Is there a way to make the queries in SQL (without resorting to PHP)? Like `JOIN` after `WHERE`? Or make two queries in one (save the first query result, and use a column value from the first result as a table name in the second query)?

Mentioned tables:

[image: screenshot of the database tables]

---

<sub>I'm still researching, and I found out that what I'm doing with the tables is called (?) "Class Table Inheritance". It seems clever for non-login related entities (when going from child to parent; e.g. staff -> user), but in reverse (parent to child, e.g. user -> staff|customer|etc.), it seems problematic. Since I figure these things as I go, I'm stuck at the moment.</sub>

<sub>One solution that just (while typing) occured to me is to use different log-in forms/pages specific to user types. The form/page could let me know the user type beforehand, but I rather not use this method. So, single log-in form for all users.</sub>

<sub>I'm calling `users` as the base/parent table, and the `stuff`, `customers`, etc. as the child tables, because first insert happens at `users`, and child tables use `user_id` from `users`.</sub>

Comment: In your `users` table, did you include the id of the owner as foreign key? That way, when using `get_staff()` or `get_customer()`, just pass the `id` instead to retrieve the specific row. I don't think `JOIN` is necessary

Comment: In some cases, I used a single table with the admin / staff / user information, after logging in, checking the allowances and dependent on the allowance or redirecting or placing view allowances throughout the site, it was my first way to deal with these problems

Comment: Since you have something to determine whether the login is a customer or staff, I don't think there will be any conflict in the `id` foreign key

Comment: @CarlBinalla Can you elaborate more (or provide code and/or db strucre)? Even if I know the `id` of the entity (staff, customer, etc.), I'd also need to know which table to look for. In the code example, I used an email, but it makes no difference even if it was an id. For example, get the user email or id from `users` table, and search a (child) table (staff, customers, ... which table?) with the email/id.

Comment: Currently, when a user is created, first I insert credentials into `users`, get the `user_id`, then insert (with the `user_id`) into other tables (staff, customer, etc.). So a row in `staff` knows about its corresponding row in `users` through `user_id` (relation is one-to-one). A row in `users` doesn't know about the corresponding row in child tables. `users` is mapped to multiple tables (relation is one-to-many). Knowing the child row id doesn't really help. See the db structures (link) in the post.

Comment: A second thought, I suppose your comment was about the current implementation, right? I know it can be improved. My point with the code was that there has to be a second check/query (and to see if it's really necessary). My first thought about your comment was that it's a new/better solution, since that's what I'm on the lookout for :)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: @philipxy No. I'm already implementing "Class Table Inheritance" (third example in the answer). My problem is related to querying in that kind of inheritance. And to be more specific, query should go from base/parent (`users`; `SELECT * FROM users ...`)  to child (`staff`, `customers`, etc.), because I don't know the type of the user that's logging in.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a union and use an alias in the query to define different fields mapping for the same name, if there is no field in one table you just cast the alias for an empty field:

```
SELECT (staff.name) as name FROM users
left JOIN staff USING (user_id)
UNION
SELECT (customers.first_name) as name FROM users
left JOIN customers USING (user_id);
```

If the userId is a PK/FK it will be only returned by one table.

Answer (score 0):

I would set **all** users login info and email to the parent table (customers and staff) and two tables with foreign id key for other data, with users.type as you suggested. It could be done with one query, too and `Switch` condition is not needed:

```
SELECT users.email,users.type,staff.field2,customers.field3 from users 
LEFT JOIN staff ON(users.type='staff' and users.id=staff.uid) 
LEFT JOIN customers ON(users.type='customers' AND users.id=customers.uid);
```

Comment: I've used something similar to this before, and it's somewhat acceptable. Is there a way to change/filter fields depending of the joined table? For example, if I query a staff, I do not want to (also) end up with other tables' fields. Currently, I end up with 30 fields.

Comment: yes, null fields are returned at the temp subtable of query. Otherwise two queries.